# Makefile:33: *** missing separator despite of having no spaces

Tags: bash, unix

I am getting the following error in my makefile despite of having no spaces on that line, I edited a part of the file by adding tabs. But on the current line " case "$UNAME" in " , I am not able to resolve it and adding a tab on that line is throwing ‘recipe commences before first target. Stop.’ error

Makefile:33: *** missing separator.  Stop

```
  #! /bin/sh Makefile
# On GNU/Linux you must: alias make "/bin/sh Makefile $1" for this to work!!
#
# PURPOSE:      Chooses specific Makefile      
#
# NORMAL USAGE: make [version-selector]
#
# SAMPLE USAGE: make 
#               make [mp][f][d] e.g. 
#               on Linux
#                  make mp (to create spider_linux_mp)
#                  make all (to create all current executables)
#                  make new (to update all current executables version)

TARGET="$1"
echo TARGET: $TARGET

DEST="DEST=_tmp"

DEBUG=

if expr "$TARGET" : '.*d' > /dev/null
    then
    DEBUG="QFFLAGS=-g QLFLAGS=-g SUFFIX=d"
    # echo DEBUG: $DEBUG
    TARGET=`echo $TARGET | tr -d 'd'`
    fi

UNAME=`uname`
#echo UNAME: $UNAME
UNAMEm=`uname -m`
#echo UNAMEm: $UNAMEm
case "$UNAME" in
#  Find current operating system
    Linux)  
    PLATFORM=_linux 
    #VERSIONS=" _linux _linux_mp_opt64  _linux_mp_intel _linux_mpi_opt64 _linux_mp_intel64 " 
    VERSIONS=" _linux _linux_mp_opt64  _linux_mp_intel  _linux_mp_intel64 " 

    if expr "$TARGET" : '.*mp' > /dev/null
    then #  Want mp with  version
    WHICH="mp"
    else
    if expr "$TARGET" : '.*f' > /dev/null
    then #  Want  version
    WHICH=""
    fi
    fi;;
esac
```

Comment: That message comes from the standard `make` command, not from `bash`. You're not running the script correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to create the alias that's decribed on the second line of the script.

Comment: i am running it using "make" command on its directory

Comment: But this isn't a makefile, it's a bash script. It's confusing, because the name of the script is `Makefile`.

Comment: The alias syntax is wrong, too. Aliases are defined as `alias name=expansion`, but the expansion can't use things like `$1` to process parameters.

Comment: thank you , i have not written this script i have downloaded it from https://spider.wadsworth.org/spider_doc/spider/docs/spider.html , but thank you i will try to correct it